# Not all currencies can be set to a view (profile) via the API

Tags: google-analytics-api

When using the [Google Analytics Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles) to manage profiles, not all currencies can be set via the API. In the interface there are more currencies available.

> The currency type associated with this view (profile), defaults to USD. The supported values are:
>   ARS, AUD, BGN, BRL, CAD, CHF, CNY, CZK, DKK, EUR, GBP, HKD, HUF, IDR, INR, JPY, KRW, LTL, MXN, NOK, NZD, PHP, PLN, RUB, SEK, THB, TRY, TWD, USD, VND, ZAR

In the interface you can set for example LVL or VEF.

Is this a bug? Or what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently that was an issue with the API.
See the [Google Analytics Management API Changelog](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/changelog#currencies).

> This is a bug fix release; it fixes an issue where a subset of
>   currencies were supported in the   [Analytics web
>   interface](https://analytics.google.com) but not in the
>   [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles#currency).
>   This release adds support for the following currencies:
>
> - UAH, AED, BOB, CLP, COP, EGP, HRK, ILS, MAD, MYR, PEN, PKR, RON, RSD, SAR, SGD, VEF, LVL
>
> For more information see:
>
> - The [Views (profiles) reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles#currency).
> - The [Currency reference](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205902) help
>     center article.

It appears to be fixed now.